# How to make thread pool run jobs on different cores in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have access to a 16-core machine to run experiment, it is shared with other people. And I have a task that can be divided nicely into totally independent jobs. So I created a thread-pool with 16 worker threads as follows (and I hope each worker thread will run in a separate core):

```
final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16);
final ExecutorCompletionService<Integer> service = new ExecutorCompletionService<Integer>(threadPool);
```

The worker threads only need to notify the main thread when they finish. The number of jobs to submit can be up to several thousands.

However, when I run `top` to check the processes, the program had actually been running in only 2 or 3 cores for all the time. At the beginning I thought the reason was that there were other processes of other people, but I were wrong. When I run another program, written in MATLAB, although the program is sequential, it uses all 16 cores.

So my program can be run concurrently in 16 cores, but it actually ran interleaving in 2 or 3 cores. My question is how to force my Java program to run 16 jobs in 16 different cores in the machine?

Thank you.

Comment: may be that the tasks submitted are getting processed fast enough that other threads are not active ? Did you check if there were any tasks that were queued up waiting for processing ?

Comment: No, this is not the case. By the time the first worker thread finished its job, the main thread had already submitted hundreds of jobs. Still only 2 or 3 cores run.

Comment: What are the tasks doing? If they're I/O bound, you may not see a lot of them running at any given time. Or they could be in contention with the other threads for some shared resources. Or they could be churning memory and triggering the garbage collector.

Comment: As others pointed out, from what information you've given so far the reason that not all cores are used has likely to do with the nature of the tasks themselves, not the scheduling. You should test with some tasks that really use the CPU by doing some calculations in a tight loop.

Comment: @Kenster: No, I'm not doing anything with I/O. All the threads do not have any communication or share resource. The only communication is to tell the main thread that job done.

Comment: Did you write a trivial example that has sixteen busy loops and checked whether that also shows the same behavior?

Comment: How does *"tell the main thread that job done"* work in particular? (Or to ask directly: Is there some `synchronized` involved?)

Comment: Are you sure that the JVM is allowed to use all 16 cores? What is the output of `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to make thread pool use some particular number of physical (or logical, if we consider Intel HyperThreading) cores - thread scheduling on such a low level is done by OS, not by JVM.

Although, I assume it would be much more productive to find out, why the pool is utilizing only a few cores. My first guess - there is something wrong with the tasks submitted to the pool. For futher analysis I'd recommend to post (or at least review by yourself) `Runnable`s and the code that submits them to thread pool.

Comment: @downvotwr Like it or not, this answer is correct. +1

Comment: Of course you should be able to saturate 16 cores like this. He's not asking to explicitly control scheduling.

Comment: @EJP: It's correct that the OS is responsible for thread scheduling. Unless I completely misread it OP doesn't care about scheduling though, he just want's to get Java to saturate all cores. Which definitely *is* possible. So I don't think this answer is very helpful regarding the OPs problem.

Comment: @JanickBernet: *My question is how to force my Java program to run 16 jobs in 16 different cores in the machine?* - sounds like I answered the question. Although, in order to *really* solve the problem, we need to find out why OPs thread pool utilize only a few cores and a first step is reviewing the code, which I suggested.

Comment: @AlexeyMalev: I agree that for the citation you provide your answer is correct. But I also think that it should be clear from the rest of the question that the OPs main concern is to be able to saturate all cores. 'There's no way to do it' in the spirit of the question is hence wrong and IMO misleading for other people that might come here. All I would ask is to make it clearer what's not possible and what is.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat relevant, depending on what the specific issue is, a thread affinity library might be helpful, e.g.:

http://openhft.net/products/thread-affinity/

This will allow you to control which cpus and cores get used by specific threads.  If the main thread is a potential bottleneck, you could use this to prevent it from getting suspended.